# <br> tag is not working in my twitter app

Tags: php, html, twitter

I crawled through Abraham's twitter class and finally made it to display my last tweet on my site. Now I am buffled to why the 
 tags are not recognized, since it is in firebug displayed as correct html. Any common reason for this?
http://liebdich.biz

The corresponding lines of PHP:

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets); 
$text = $tweets[0] -> text;
echo $text;
```

Thank you!!

Comment: How are you giving the `<br/>` to the system?  It's likely a case of the `<` and `>` being translated to HTML acceptable codes `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectfully.

Comment: I inspected the element on firebug, i guess there is a single space between your br tag.remove the space between `<br` and `/>`

Comment: @dreamweiver looks like it works good then - but why would a space make a difference? I've seen <br /> before and they worked..

Comment: @DavidStarkey Still not working, watch it. But thanks!
Here is the code:
    `$tweets = $connection-    >get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?    screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
     
    $text = $tweets[0] -> text;
    echo $text;`

Comment: @baustellenServer Look at your source code, , it literally says `Test &lt;br /&gt; test`. Got it? Something escaped your `<` and `>`!

Comment: @MightyPork What is escaping it then? I cannot see a `/` in the source code.

Comment: Is that `<br>` written though Twitter? I'm pretty sure Twitter doesn't preserve html tags.

Comment: Could somebody who is downvoting my thread please just give the right answer then? Thank you!!

Comment: Dunno what's your `source code`. Perhaps if you post it here, you will get some help that will be more useful that this.

Comment: @NicklasNygren Yes, it is written through twitter. But when PHP pastes the string into the HTML, HTML should just see it as a `<br>`tag, not? :)

Comment: No, because the string it receives from Twitter is literally `&lt;br&gt;`. I'll post an answer on how to potentially reverse this.

Comment: @NicklasNygren This is the twitter text at the moment. If I try it with <br> it does not work either, I just tried because of MightyPork. I send the <br> version now again for you. ;)

Comment: @dreamweiver The space before the slash is written on W3Schools. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: @baustellenServer: Try the function provided in my answer. It should solve your problem regardless of how you write the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter transmits html entities of the tag characters. If you really want PHP to write out HTML for you, try `html_entity_decode`:

```
html_entity_decode("&lt;br&gt;");
```

Gives:

```
<br>
```

See https://www.php.net/function.html-entity-decode for more information.

Bear in mind that Twitter escapes HTML for a reason. Reverse it at your own risk.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I think you were a bit too fast though. I wrote the html entities in my twitter text, if I do it with `<br>` it is not escaped, as it is at the moment. Have a look again, please.

Comment: Yes, it is. The source code clearly says `Test &lt;br /&gt; test`. That will be *displayed* as <br />, but it will not achieve the function of the `<br />` html tag. See the difference. Try my solution, trust me.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was too fast here. ;) It actually works, even when I use <br> in the twitter text. Thank you!!

Comment: Ah, now I know what you mean. In the source code is different to firebug (or chrome developer tool). Learned another thing! :) Thanks!!